# How To Import pyQt5 QWebView in Python

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebview

I am trying with this

```
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage, QWebView
```

but it does not find the Module.. not even with QtWebKitEngineWidgets

Comment: What version of pyqt5 do you have and what is your OS? You could also explain how you have installed pyqt5.

Comment: Qt version: 5.9.1  on macOS Sierra 10.12 python 3.6.. I think i had install it with pip or brew can't really remember as I was trying more than once

Comment: If you have installed with pip or brew, I do not think you have installed that module, the problem that module depends on chromium and its .dlyb, in order to have that module you must download the source code and compile it manually.